# Implementing a circuit on Printed circuit board

Tags: pcb

I have a circuit on my breadboard, which is not too sophisticated. The company i am working with want me to present it. If they want it on PCB i don't kn ow how to do it. It is too daunting to make by hand for me. I am not a technician.

Is there any companies that makes PCB for people who designed circuits?

Comment: Yes there are. BUT you probably also need somebody who understands electronics well to check your circuit. I see many circuits which "sort of work" but which show immediately that the designer did not really understand what they were doing. A major risk is that the circuit will do well enough to be accepted but will be a disaster in practice.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/21172/looking-for-a-good-freeware-open-source-pcb-design-software-equivalent-to-altium http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7941/schematic-capture-pcb-layout-program-recommendations

Comment: Companies you hire for this are both going to be greatly localized in time and in location. Yes, you can hire someone anywhere, but often you will need someone with a similar language, and companies that do this will change often. This question is also really off topic, posting companies you can hire here is not feasible, there are many companies that exist that will do it. You can even hire people from places like freelancer.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [Fritzing](http://fritzing.org/).

Fritzing is a user friendly electronics design package letting you transfer your design from breadboard to PCB. Once your design is complete, you can order PCBs directly from http://fab.fritzing.org/fritzing-fab

While Fritzing may not be ideal for complex designs, it's a great tool and lowers the barrier for PCB design.

Comment: that is cool man. i think this is the thing i need, since i have no practical talent and courage to do my own PCB.

Answer (score 2):

PCB design is not something you can start with quickly. First thing you need is an **EDA** (Electronic Design Automation) package, that's your CAD. You use the EDA to design your schematics (which for a breadboard you may have done with paper and pencil) and convert them into a PCB layout. EDAs often have their proprietary file formats, but for delivering your work to a PCB shop there's a standard format: Gerber, which your EDA should be able to produce. The Gerber files (one for each layer) together with drill information allow the shop to produce your board.

Creating a board layout you have to work with DRCs (Design Rule Check), which checks if you're not violating certain rules, like components or traces too close too each other. Your EDA will have a standard set of design rules, but you should be able to change them to your needs. This requires some experience, just like creating a layout in the first place. If you start with a rather complex design (many components, several of the with high pin count) it's very likely that you get stuck just trying to place the parts on the board so that the nets are routable. Many design companies have PCB design engineers who're doing just that. That's because experience is important and with experience comes intuition. An experienced layout designer may do a nearly optimal component placement from the first time, while someone with less experience may have to start all over again a few times.

[Eagle](http://www.cadsoftusa.com/eagle-pcb-design-software/) seems to be a popular EDA software around here, but I haven't used it myself, so I can't comment on its ease of use/learning curve. There's a free version with limitations; IIRC your board is limited to 80mm x 60mm.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a same as circuit as your breadboard, you have two options to do:
1). give it to electronic design company.
2). clone each parttern layerby yourself,trough individually scan the board's layers  and design software, which is a bit complex. Of course, you can send the board to PCB manufacturer,normally,which knows how to do,and then make boards to you.