# Looking for an easy to use circuit design software similar for beginner

Tags: digital-logic, schematics, simulation, software

I'm teaching my son digital circuit design. I am looking for an easy to use design tool that can serve to sketch out the circuit and simulate it before we go and blow chips and money.  The ideal product would have the following features:

- Schema editor
- Simulator
- Ability to roll schema into reusable a component or module
- Support for primitive operations (AND, OR, NOT, NAND, ETC.)
- Intuitive User Interface
- No Java (No offense to java lovers)
- Runs on Windows 7

I don't mind paying for a quality piece of software provided it is reasonably priced.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1222/what-are-low-cost-circuit-and-pcb-design-software?rq=1

Comment: I am not looking for PCB functionality and my needs are low end.

Comment: Ah okay - then this question may be of use: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1206/what-are-the-freeware-spice-simulators-available

Comment: Or this: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7022/circuit-simulation-software

Answer (score 4):

Consider [LTspice](http://www.linear.com/designtools/software/). It has most of what you want - though it has a learning curve - and a [very big user's community](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/LTspice/) which has created a lot of device models, documentation etc...

While it's most for analog circuits, it can be used for doing digital circuits too.