# Program to draw pinouts (and easily visualize pin's multiplexed functions)

Tags: diagram, pinout

Documenting an electronics project is also an important task if it will be used by someone else other than the hardware designer(s). Right now I need to draw a diagram for a breakout board in order to show what functions are available on each pin. Something like the following diagram (of mbed):

[image]

Can someone recommends me a program that allows me to easily draw such diagrams?

Comment: Not the simplest way, but probably I'd use a vector graphics editor like Inkscape.

Comment: Pretty much any graphics program can do this, if you're comfortable using it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Fritzing](http://fritzing.org/home/) is pretty nice for this, there are a bunch of libraries built in and available for download that have a lot of the more popular platforms made, and you can define your own parts using an svg editor like [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/). It's particularly nice for having defined pin areas for your lines to connect to so things don't break if you drag it around.

[draw.io](https://www.draw.io/) is good for doing quick block diagrams and simplified wiring and is browser based with nice cloud integration. But I haven't tried to use images of PCBs for pinouts with it so it might not be the right thing for that.

**edit 2/22/2020**: here is a good video showing how the Adafruit feather diagrams are made: https://youtu.be/ndVs1UvK6AE

Sparkfun also has a repo on github for generating SVG elements that they use for their "graphical datasheet" pinouts. I have not tried it but Sparkfun does a lot of these types of pinouts: https://github.com/sparkfun/Graphical_Datasheets

Someone has taken this further with a python script, which may be a good option for advanced users if you don't mind learning how to use the format: https://github.com/stevenj/GenPinoutSVG

Also adding this link to another GitHub repo to generate nice looking SVG representations of PCB designs from a KiCad board file. I have not used this myself either, but it looks like it would pair really well with the way Fritzing defines parts: https://github.com/yaqwsx/PcbDraw

**edit 9/4/2021**:  Adding a link to a tool called Pinion, which can create interactive pinout diagrams from KiCAD PCBs: https://yaqwsx.github.io/Pinion/

Answer (score 9):

- **[Latex](http://www.latex-project.org/) + [TikZ](http://www.texample.net/tikz/)** is popular in academia and you can use it to programmatically create very clean diagrams.
- **[Illustrator](http://www.adobe.com/products/illustrator.html)** is more user friendly, mass-marketed and has a more shallow learning curves.
- **[Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/)** is open source software similar to Illustrator.
- **[Visio](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio/)** is a diagram tool produced by Microsoft.  Widely used in engineering departments.

Comment: Microsoft Visio is good for this too

Comment: I made it a community wiki. Feel free to add your other recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not the "right" app, but I use Powerpoint for stuff like this.

I also sometimes use the online diagrammer at https://www.lucidchart.com/