# What software to graphically design a simple schematic?

Tags: schematics, cpu, computer-architecture

I need to draw a schematic similar to that shown in the figure attached in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8199449).
Are there softwares that allow to graphically design a schematic like that?

Comment: That's a block diagram, not a schematic.

Comment: Diagramming software has been discussed many tines on EE.SE.  [Here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/73780/program-to-draw-pinouts-and-easily-visualize-pins-multiplexed-functions), for example.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Visio is a good choice for these type of diagrams. Try searching for Visio alternative for bigger selection.

Comment: What makes Visio a "good" choice versus a "possible" choice?

Comment: Well, so I could choose between _Visio_ and _LibreOffice/OpenOffice.org Draw_.

Comment: I have browsed through many other programs to find alternative when I didn't have the license for Visio on Windows or when I looked for an alternative on Mac. Visio was just the most usable for the tasks I needed (and some were very similar to what enzom83 asked). Other programs were either too bloated or too basic.