# Software to make a simple Pinout Diagram

Tags: software, diagram, pinout

I would like to make a simple diagram showing the pin outs of all of the pins on a board that I have. I would like to do something like the image in [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/73780/program-to-draw-pinouts-and-easily-visualize-pins-multiplexed-functions?newreg=94c81ca4bb594775a58b5873496f0181) post. All of the answers to this question either covered electrical schematic software, or doing it completely from scratch. Is there any type of software where I can specific the dimensions of a header, and label each pin? I do not mind something even as simple as this:

[image: pinout]

Comment: That seems quite doable in any spreadsheet software (MS Excel, Google Sheets, OpenOffice, etc..). Then you have options like Adobe Illustrator, Indesign, CorelDraw, Inkscape, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know what a CAD package is?

Any one of number of computer aided design (CAD) software packages would allow you to create the type of thing that you showed in the picture. The names of a few of these packages that pop into mind are:

1. AutoCAD
2. DraftSight
3. Visio

If your tables are limited to looking pretty much like your snippet diagram then even Excel spreadsheet software can be used to show such diagrams.

[image]

Comment: Excel. Thank you so much, I feel like a complete idiot. I have a student SolidWorks package, but Excel should be enough for my needs.

Comment: Excel it is then. Here is a template that made the above: http://carousel-design.com/PinoutTable.xlsx