# Software to create board pinout diagram

Tags: pinout, board

What software is used to create this (very cool) pinout diagram?

[image]

Comment: Image is attributed to [Alberto Piganti - PighiXXX](https://www.pinterest.it/pighixxx/_saved/).  Site has a link to message PighiXXX.

Comment: PighiXXX dropped off the Internet some years ago. He did some work for Adafruit and they have a video on Youtube that shows the system they subsequently set up to create their own versions of these diagrams for the development boards they design. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tAKLygjfO_U

Comment: Not exactly this format, but people may be interested in https://pinout.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html if you are prepared to use/learn python.

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely done in a graphic design program.

It is not "cool" because the actual data is not available for use in any convenient way.

Pinouts should be presented in tabular form, excel-style, that can be copy-pasted in bulk easily, for example into the Altium tabular pinout editor, or into code. When the only pinout available is a graphic file, or a pdf where the table [can't be cleanly copy-pasted](https://resources.altium.com/p/creating-high-pin-count-schematic-symbols-quickly), you have to do everything by hand, which is error-prone.

Many manufacturers provide pinouts for high pin count devices like microcontrollers in spreadsheet format. Then it's very simple to import in CAD to make a symbol, or make another column with the function name you'll assign to each pin, and convert the whole thing into #defines to import in your code without any chance of error. That saves a lot of time.

Comment: I agree that the diagram is no substitute for a table.  At the same time, the table is a poor substitute for a diagram.  Raw machine-readable data and visual presentation should both be provided.

Answer (score 0):

Relevant previous SE question:

[Program to draw pinouts (and easily visualize pin's multiplexed functions)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/73780/program-to-draw-pinouts-and-easily-visualize-pins-multiplexed-functions)

Lots of ideas are mentioned, but in particular there is this video which demonstrates how such a diagram is made in Inkscape:

*Feather Diagram Walk-Through for Adafruit*

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ndVs1UvK6AE