# How to given power for nRF8002 chip?

Tags: power-supply, psoc

How to given power for nRF8002 chip?Pin 1-4 used for supplying power,but i didn't know the how power is given(1.9 - 3.6 V).nRF8002 development kit is the only solution for configuring this soc?

[Data sheet for nRF8002 soc](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDcQFjAC&url=http://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/nordic/download_resource/17517/5/15994878&ei=LDb7UtyFPIO4rgfg94AQ&usg=AFQjCNG0l_gSrNVqT-r-QlhPj2kuU5zjQw&bvm=bv.61190604,d.bmk)

Thanks for your valuable comments in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you probably have some sort of module as those pin numbers don't match the datasheet. You should mention what it is and give a link to a datasheet or product information.

Comment: My idea is develop a ble device from nRF8002 soc chip.?is It possible without extra cost(without development board).?

Comment: That IC SoC has 17 power pins, and yes, they all have to be connected. If you don't want to buy a dev-kit, you will have to have a custom PCB made for the IC.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use a Development Kit you will need to design your custom PCB for that IC.

To power the IC you will need connect all power pins as said the datasheet:

[image]

Where VDD is the Power (1.9 - 3-6V) and the VSS is the Ground (0V).

The recommend voltage to this IC is 3.3V, and have a lot of switch power supplys designs for this voltage, you can use [this tool](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/analog/webench/overview.page) to create your own, with BOM, schematic and PCB if you want.

If you do not care to use exactly this IC you could simple use some [Bluetooth Module](https://www.google.com.br/search?hl=pt-BR&q=bluetooh%20module#hl=pt-BR&q=bluetooth%20module&spell=1) with some simple MCU like an Arduino.

Comment: How to design pcb board using this soc.?Please provide any resource for developing pcb board.Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: To desgin a PCB project you will need some software to do it like Altium Designer, Eagle PCB, or others...

Comment: Take a look [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/40388/high-quality-free-pcb-software-download/42121#42121)