# Free simple application for making a prototype shield

Tags: software

Is there a simple and free application for 'designing' a prototype shield (like [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Free-Shipping-New-Logging-Recorder-Data-Logger-Module-Shield-V1-0-for-Arduino-UNO-SD-Card/32773073633.html?spm=2114.01010208.3.1.TkDwEs&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_4_10152_10151_10065_10150_10068_10136_10137_10138_10060_10062_10141_10056_10055_10054_128_10059_10099_10103_10102_10096_10148_10147_10052_10053_10050_10107_10142_10051_10143_10084_10083_10080_10082_10081_10110_10111_10112_10113_10114_10037_10033_10032_10078_10079_10077_10073_10070_10123_10124-10050_10111_10037_10077,searchweb201603_4,afswitch_1,ppcSwitch_7&btsid=0771a5d3-d8ec-49f9-95e9-0e14395fd11e&algo_expid=7b1ee2fe-d291-4a8c-a6ae-90c0d8c61421-0&algo_pvid=7b1ee2fe-d291-4a8c-a6ae-90c0d8c61421)?)

Currently I use Excel and a 'Above' and 'Below' side next to each other but it gets messy already with such a small shield layout.

Comment: Do you mean PCB design like Autocad Eagle, or something else?

Comment: Well I do not have the intention to make a full fledged PCB, just some hand-soldered proto shield ... but I'm fully new to it, so I wonder if there are software tools for it. I never heard of Autocad Eagle but I will take a look.

Comment: Not sure what you’re willing to do, but I tin some people use [fritzing](http://fritzing.org/home/) for simple designs. I never used it myself.

Comment: I want to check how I can best fill something like the example (see the link to 'this' or a bigger proto shield.

Comment: Stop calling PCBs "shields". By using commercial terminology instead of standard one, you're hurting your ability to search properly. Google for `PCB design software` and observe how results get much more relevant compared to `Shield design software`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are low cost circuit and PCB design software?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1222/what-are-low-cost-circuit-and-pcb-design-software)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside the Arduino world, that is called a Printed Circuit Board (PCB).

We use electronic CAD programs to draw the schematic diagram and lay out the the PC board.  The CAD program will produce Gerber photoplot files and NC drill files that a PCB shop can use to make the final boards.

Two CAD programs often used are Eagle and KiCAD.